# Get paged result containing specific record with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, pagination

I'm working on an admin view that lists ASP.NET Identity users with a link to create a new user. Right now the link just takes you to a new page with a form for creating a new user. After saving the new user, it sends you back to the user list page. The list page already accepts pageNumber and pageSize parameters (where pageSize is the number of users to retrieve and display at once.) What I want to do is display the page that contains the user that was just created, but how can I determine which page that user falls on?

I need to know the index of that user in the set of all users but I don't want to retrieve all users to do it. Is there a way to get Entity Framework to essentially return the [Row_Number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) does. of my specific record? Otherwise I feel like I would just need to create a stored procedure the give me the index, but can I do that with the code-first Identity database (I'm new to both code-first and Identity.)

---

**Edits:**
Requested Code Excerpt (modified for brevity):

```
public ActionResult Users(int? pageNum, int? pageSize)
{
    ActionResult response;

    AccountAdminUsersVM vm = new AccountAdminUsersVM();
    vm.PageSize = pageSize ?? 50;
    vm.CurrentPage = pageNum ?? 1;

    try
    {
        int totalCount;
        vm.UsersPage = GetUsers(vm.CurrentPage, vm.PageSize, out totalCount);
        vm.TotalCount = totalCount;

        ...

        response = View(vm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }

    return response;
}

private List<ApplicationUser> GetUsers(int page, int pageSize, out int totalCount)
{
    totalCount = UserManager.Users.Count();
    return UserManager.Users
            .OrderBy(u => u.UserName)
            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();
}

private ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
}
```

Here's what I imagine the SQL would need to look like (except the order by column would need to be parameterized too):

```
SELECT  t1.RowNum
FROM    (
            SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserName) AS RowNum
            FROM    AspNetUsers
        ) t1
WHERE t1.Id = @Id
```

That seems like a tall order for Linq.

Comment: Wont it be added as the last record (or are you doing some sorting in the paged results)?

Comment: They will be ordered by some property/column. Currently it's UserName.

Comment: The getting the 'row number' will not help. You need to get the index of the new object in the sorted collection

Answer (score 1):

When you call context.SaveChanges() / await AsyncSaveChanges() the result contains the newly created entity. You could pass that back to your redirect action.

Edit: Needs a call for ToList(). So it won't be lazy loading, and if a lot of application users are expected then this won't be a recommended option.

```
//this is how you can get the index of the user in an ordered list. "_newUserName" is being passed in, either as a User object or string (your call)

var index = UserManager.Users.OrderBy(a=>a.UserName).ToList().Select((user, index) => new {user,index}).Where(a=>a.user.UserName == "_newUserName").Select(a=>a.index).FirstOrDefault();

//then determine the page new user sits on
var page = (index / pageSize ) + 1;
return UserManager.Users
        .OrderBy(u => u.UserName)
        .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: And then what do I do with that entity to determine which pagination page to display?

Comment: could you please paste your code here, that would help me answer your question.

Comment: Added. The CreateUser action (not shown) redirects back to Users. The structure of my Users action isn't set in stone. I'm kind of just messing around with Identity at the moment.

Comment: just edited my answer to show how to get the index of the new user, and it's corresponding page based on pageSize. Hope it helps.

Comment: So close! I get this exception which sounds like it's unable to convert it to SQL?: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[TLGI.CRM.MVCWeb.Models.ApplicationUser,System.Int32]] Select[ApplicationUser,<>f__AnonymousType1`2](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TLGI.CRM.MVCWeb.Models.ApplicationUser], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[TLGI.CRM.MVCWeb.Models.ApplicationUser,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType1`2[TLGI.CRM.MVCWeb.Models.ApplicationUser,System.Int32]]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Correct, I entirely overlooked the fact that Users is returning IQuaryable. You'll need to call ToList after Users, or call OrderBy before Select and then ToList(). That said we both know that is going to be expensive the more users you have in your application. So If you don't expect a lot of users, it could be an option, else I think the stored procedure is the way to go.